# Не работает replace с /

Tags: python

Хочу заменить слеши падает с ошибкой, что не так?

```
dst_sav = r'D:\home\123'


dst_sav.replace(r"\", r"/")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А лучше всего пользуйтесь os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '123') или Path.cwd() / '123'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

К сожалению, модификатор `r` не может помочь в случае бэкслэша, завершающего строку - это особенность интерпретатора питона, она не чинится. Тут только экранировать этот символ вручную. Ну и тогда тут `r`-строки вообще не нужны:

```
dst_sav = r'D:\home\123'
dst_sav.replace("\\", "/")
# 'D:/home/123'
```